# Text processing using bash

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

I have a vmstat dump file that has the header and values in this format

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------  
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st  
12  0 5924396 20810624 548548 935160    0    0     0     5    0    0 60  5 34  0  0  
12  0 5924396 20768588 548548 935160    0    0     0     0 1045 1296 99  0  0  0  0  
12  0 5924396 20768968 548548 935452    0    0     0    32 1025 1288 100  0  0  0  0  
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------  
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st  
 4  0 5924396 20768724 548552 935408    0    0     0    92 1093 1377 33  0 67  0  0
```

I'm writing a script in bash that extracts just the lines containing lines with numbers i.e. values and remove all lines containing the alphabet. How do I do that

Comment: `grep '[0-9]' filename` should work. Then save the output to whatever file you want. (`awk` could do the same pretty easily.) I'm assuming the file is as you show - the non-numeric lines have *no* numbers in them. If this isn't the case, you could tweak the search.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a lines with numbers and tabs\spaces only, `grep -P "^[0-9\ \t]*$"`  should helps you.

```
$> cat ./text | grep -P "^[0-9\ \t]*$"
12  0 5924396 20810624 548548 935160    0    0     0     5    0    0 60  5 34  0  0  
12  0 5924396 20768588 548548 935160    0    0     0     0 1045 1296 99  0  0  0  0  
12  0 5924396 20768968 548548 935452    0    0     0    32 1025 1288 100  0  0  0  0  
 4  0 5924396 20768724 548552 935408    0    0     0    92 1093 1377 33  0 67  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat filename | grep "[0-9]"`

Comment: You can do away with `cat` and simply do `grep <pattern> filename`